# PHP doesn't run through Snow Leopard Web Sharing

Tags: php, apache, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I've followed all the tutorials and uncommented the relevant lines in httpd.conf, but PHP files do not render under Web Sharing.

The server just serves up the source code instead of running it.

I know that PHP works, because I can run it straight from the Terminal using the "php" command.

What is happening here?

Comment: PHP in the terminal is a bit different from PHP in a web server.  I.e. just because the CLI version of PHP works, doesn't mean that web server module works.

Comment: I guess, post the relevant bits of httpd.conf.

Comment: Check also the error log for any relevant error Apache reports.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to system preferences and go to Sharing - is Web Sharing enabled?

Comment: Yes, hence I am able to access said PHP file through sf.local/~sajseven/... And so on and so forth.

Comment: @user383084 Did you restart Apache?

Answer (score 0):

After you changed the /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file, did you restart Apache?

Answer (score 0):

Try mamp (Mac Apache Mysql PHP). http://www.mamp.info It works brilliant under Snow Leopard 10.6.4